# Easily intimidated/intimidated easily - word arrangement

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm easily intimidated.

I'm intimidated easily.

Is the second sentence wrong? I looked into how you say it, and I couldn't find any results matching the second sentence. Does it meaning of this sentence change with the arrangement of its words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are good. Placing the adverb at the end of the sentence puts a little more emphasis on it. If you aren't trying to emphasise it, then "I'm easily intimidated" is a bit smoother. That's the only tiny difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine, you often have a choice of adverb placement, either before or after the main verb.

For example:

- I posted quickly without researching.
- I quickly posted without researching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm intimidated easily. This is not the normal way to write this phrase. It is normally written in the format of your first example.

> I'm easily intimidated.

Easily is an adverb. Adverbs are words used to modify verbs. They usually express the manner in which something is done. They are also used to modify adjectives or another adverb and usually goes before them.

Note; Enough is an exception to this rule. It goes after the adjective or adverb it modifies.

Ref [Adverbs](https://www.englishgrammar.org/adjective-adverb-2/)